# PHP:Having issue while generating PDF in Russian language using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I want to generate invoices in PDF format but, in generated PDF Russian characters are converted into some unknown characters.

[image]

**The value in database is :**

```
Company name : Тртиел ООД
Address : ул. ген. Гурко 66
City : София
Country : Българяи
```

**Here is the code :**

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'KOI8-R',"'".$result_company[$i]['value']."'")
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,5, iconv('UTF-8', 'KOI8-R',"'".$my_result[$i]['value']."'"),1);
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can convert from UTF-8 to KOI8-R in FPDF - it is normally recommended that you convert to ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 instead. If this is not possible then you will need to use something like tFPDF, which is a modified version of FPDF that natively supports UTF-8 output.

To download the tFPDF class or find out more information please visit the official [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) site.

Comment: Having just looked in the FPDF "makefont" directory, there are font maps for KOI8-R so you could also try converting your fonts and then loading them in as custom fonts.